# How to properly compare POST data to database data?

Tags: php, compare

I created a function that checks if value in database is the same as value from submitted form. The function has to compare both data and update only if they are different, but doesn't work properly. `$value` comes from `$_POST` textarea:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT info FROM database1 WHERE id=1 "); $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($value == $row[0]) echo "The same!";
else echo "They are different!";
```

**The problem is about line breaks**. Data from database in html source view looks like that:

```
line1
line2
```

Data from POST in html source view:

```
line1\r\nline2
```

So when I compare these both it's different, but in fact they are the same from database point of view. I tried `$value = str_replace('\r\n','', $value);` and `$value = str_replace('\r\n','<br>', $value);` for data from POST and it doesn't help. Maybe I should replace `\r\n` into something different, but for what?

Comment: Proper is if you don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore because they're deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: Do the replacement in both the values, not just Posted value

Comment: I know I should use new ones, but it's only for local simple tasks. Not for any serious coding.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ($value == mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]))
```

The function `mysql_real_escape_string()` convert string as you convert post data

Comment: pleased to help you :)